# Ambiguity in array of 2d arrays declaration in C

Tags: c++, c

I'm going through a code where I encountered this line of code. 
I'm not able to understand  `unsigned char (*data)[int][int]` declared as argument in the function, if I consider this piece of code as an array of two-dimensional arrays(I'm passing array of 2d arrays) and then if I modify the code as `unsigned char *data[int][int]` should this not work?.

Comment: `unsigned char (*data)[int][int]` .. pointer to a two-D array.

Comment: And `unsigned char *data[int][int]` is a "2d" array of pointers.

Comment: If in doubt try this: [`unsigned char (*data)[10][10]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=unsigned+char+%28*data%29%5B10%5D%5B10%5D%3B) vs. [`unsigned char *data[10][10]`](https://cdecl.org/?q=unsigned+char+*data%5B10%5D%5B10%5D%3B)

Comment: @SouravGhosh, could you please elucidate how? or can you provide any sources?

Comment: @Scheff I've tried first one it works, but the secondd one throws an error during compile time.

Comment: @SomeProgrammerDude, could you please elucidate how? or can you provide any sources?

Comment: The second has a different meaning as already pointed out. The compile time error is type mismatch?

Comment: A pointer to arrays of arrays of something is not the same than an array of arrays of pointers to something. ;-)

Comment: `unsigned char (*data)[int][int]` is not valid C. Do you mean `unsigned char (*data)[x][y]`? Also, an array of 2D arrays is `type name [x][y][z]` which has no relation to any of this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it won't work. Because these declarations declare different types which are incompatible.

`unsigned char (*data)[2][2]`: declare data as **pointer to array** 2 of array 2 of unsigned char (from https://cdecl.org/)

```
+---+      +---+---+
|  -+----->|   |   |
+---+      +---+---+
data       |   |   |
           +---+---+
           unsigned char [2][2]
```

---

`unsigned char *data[2][2]`: declare data as **array** 2 of array 2 **of pointer** to unsigned char

```
                   +---+---+
 unsigned char <---+-  |  -+---> unsigned char
                   +---+---+
 unsigned char <---+-  |  -+---> unsigned char
                   +---+---+
                     data
```